# Scala class not found on classpath when specifying jar in classpath

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I am attempting to use [ScalaCheck](http://www.scalacheck.org). Below is my `HelloWorld.scala` Scala code which imports from `ScalaCheck` and uses the `Gen.const` method.

```
package com

import org.scalacheck._
import org.scalacheck.Gen._
import org.scalacheck.Arbitrary.arbitrary

sealed abstract class Tree
case class Node(left: Tree, right: Tree, v: Int) extends Tree
case object Leaf extends Tree

object HelloWorld {
 val genLeaf = Gen.const(Leaf)

 def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
 }
}
```

Compile by typing (this works)

```
scalac -cp scalacheck_2.11-1.11.5.jar com/HelloWorld.scala
```

Execute by typing (2 alternatives)

```
scala -cp scalacheck_2.11-1.11.5.jar com.HelloWorld
scala -cp "scalacheck_2.11-1.11.5.jar;./com" com.HelloWorld
```

Output of scala

```
No such file or class on classpath: com.HelloWorld
```

When I remove all ScalaCheck code in `HelloWorld.scala` and compile without using the -cp flag everything works. When adding the ScalaCheck code and the jar to the -cp flag, I get the above error.

How do I correctly setup the classpath?

(Versions:

```
scalac -version
```

Scala compiler version 2.11.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

```
scala -version
```

Scala code runner version 2.11.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

)

OS: Linux

Comment: try this scala -cp "scalacheck_2.11-1.11.5.jar;." com.HelloWorld

Comment: I stiil get the error "No such file or class on classpath: com.HelloWorld"

Comment: You'll be much, much happier if you start using a build system as soon as you can. This would require two lines of configuration and SBT and then you never have to worry about your classpath again (not really, but closer).

Comment: I was trying to get this working using first principals (from the cmd line using scalac and scala). With SBT ScalaCheck is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which OS are you using? If not Windows, the path separator should be `:`, try this

```
scala -cp "scalacheck_2.11-1.11.5.jar:." com.HelloWorld
```

Comment: Yes works with : (colon) as seperator. Thank you Loki.